# Splitting GPX track into 3 pieces, removing 2nd and moving 1st to 3rd

Tags: gpx

I have recorded a track from a race and my Suunto Spartan Sport watch screw it. Suunto somehow recorded it with wrong coordinates (shifted the first part ~1 km far) and it resulted +1 km and wrongly calculated pace.

I am looking for a solution to fix the GPX.

I have this track

[image: Track screwed by Suunto Spartan Sport]

1. Is it possible to split this track into 3 pieces:

- 1a to 2a
- 2a to 2b
- 2b till the end

2. remove the 2nd part (2a to 2b)
3. and move the 1st part (1a to 2a) to 2b by keeping the track points, the time information but adjusting the coordinates accordingly?

I have tried so far only online apps like https://gpx.studio and http://mygpsfiles.com/app. I was able to move 1 point to another place but I wasn't able to select a bunch of points and move them together.

Comment: Possibly try QGIS and edit tools

Answer (score 0):

Since .gpx is just a xml extension, you can open the file in your favorit editor (e.g. notepad ++) and delete the wrong entries. I would recommend that you copy your file, so that its no problem if you delete too much.

Comment: okay, thanks! I was able to delete the unnecessary part. My main issue is that I don't find a tool which makes me able to select all the points between  1a and 2a and move them together 1km down (South), preserving all the time/pace information but changing the coordinates. Can you recommend me an editor. I use linux so windows or Mac is not an option.